# Mean of non-central Poisson deviance distribution is lower than that of the associated central distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution, deviance, non-central

We have observed some strange behaviour regarding distributions of Poisson deviance statistics.
In short, we find for certain Poisson parameters, that the non-central deviances are smaller than the central deviances, completely contrary to intuition.
More detail below:

## Background

We are using Poisson deviance to analyze the results of radiation detection simulations. Specifically, we have two models $\boldsymbol{\lambda}_0$ and $\boldsymbol{\lambda}_1$ that can give rise to a vector $\boldsymbol{n}$ of counts at each measurement, e.g.,
$$
\boldsymbol{n} \sim \text{Poisson}(\boldsymbol{\lambda}_{0}).
$$

We are interested in finding how often a measurement $\boldsymbol{n}$ drawn from the alternate model $\boldsymbol{\lambda}_1$ "looks like" it was drawn from the null model $\boldsymbol{\lambda}_0$. To accomplish this, we use the Poisson deviance
$$
D(\boldsymbol{n} | \boldsymbol{\lambda}) = 2 \left[ \boldsymbol{n} \log(\boldsymbol{n}) - \boldsymbol{n} \log(\boldsymbol{\lambda}) + \boldsymbol{\lambda - \boldsymbol{n}} \right]
$$
and consider two different distributions of deviance statistics. First, we consider the deviance $D(\boldsymbol{n}_0 | \boldsymbol{\lambda}_0)$ between the null model $\boldsymbol{\lambda}_0$ and a sample $\boldsymbol{n}_0$ drawn from it.
Then, we consider the "non-central" deviance $D(\boldsymbol{n}_1 | \boldsymbol{\lambda}_0)$ between a sample $\boldsymbol{n}_1$ of the alternate model $\boldsymbol{\lambda}_1$ computed assuming that $\boldsymbol{\lambda}_0$ was the true model.
The distributions of these $D$ statistics can be Monte Carlo simulated, or approximated analytically via shifted Gamma distributions.
We can then define a decision rule for deciding $\boldsymbol{\hat{\lambda}} = \boldsymbol{\lambda}_0$ vs $\boldsymbol{\lambda}_1$, and subsequently compute the false negative probability that $\boldsymbol{n}$ "looks like" it was drawn from the  null model $\boldsymbol{\lambda}_0$ when really it was generated from the alternate model $\boldsymbol{\lambda}_1$.

## Problem

The problem we see is that occasionally, the distribution of the non-central deviances $D(\boldsymbol{n}_1 | \boldsymbol{\lambda}_0)$ is below that of the central deviances $D(\boldsymbol{n}_0 | \boldsymbol{\lambda}_0)$.
For instance, consider a simple model with $N = 10^5$ measurements and constant Poisson rates
$$
    \boldsymbol{\lambda}_0 = 2.80 \cdot \vec{1}_N
$$
$$
    \boldsymbol{\lambda}_1 = 2.82 \cdot \vec{1}_N
$$
where $\vec{1}_N$ denotes a vector of $1$'s of length $N$.
Our results for the central (blue) and non-central (orange) deviances are shown in the figure below.
The non-central deviance distribution is lower than the central one, leading to a strange false negative probability of ${>}0.5$.

[image: bad_deviance]

Intuitively, we would expect that the deviances from the correct model $\boldsymbol{\lambda}_0$ computed using the incorrect model $\boldsymbol{\lambda}_1$ should be larger than those computed using the correct $\boldsymbol{\lambda}_0$. Or at least, that this should be true on average. If we write out the difference in means
$$
    \Delta \equiv \mathbb{E}[D(\boldsymbol{n}_1 | \boldsymbol{\lambda}_0)] - \mathbb{E}[D(\boldsymbol{n}_0 | \boldsymbol{\lambda}_0)]
$$
$$
    \Delta = 2 \sum_i \mathbb{E}[\lambda_{0i} - n\log\lambda_{0i} + n\log n -n | \lambda_{1i}] - 2 \sum_i \mathbb{E}[\lambda_{0i} - n\log\lambda_{0i} + n\log n -n | \lambda_{0i}]
$$
$$
    \Delta = 2 \sum_i (\lambda_{0i} - \lambda_{1i} + \lambda_{0i}\log \lambda_{0i} - \lambda_{1i} \log \lambda_{0i} + \mathbb{E}[n\log n | \lambda_{1i}] - \mathbb{E}[n\log n | \lambda_{0i}] )
$$
we would intuitively expect this never to be negative. However, as our example shows, this is not always the case. In fact this problem seems to arise under two conditions:

1. The two model-predicted count vectors are similar across most measurements: $\lambda_{0i} \simeq \lambda_{1i}$.
2. The model-predicted counts are small on average: $\lambda_i \lesssim 10$.

## Distillation down to a single measurement

To simplify, let us model a scenario with a single measurement: $N=1$.
We will explore the behaviour of $\Delta$ in the two above conditions where $\lambda_0 \simeq \lambda_1 \lesssim 10$.
If we plot the difference in means $\Delta$ as a function of $\lambda_0$ and $\lambda_1$, we obtain the following figures:

[image: contour0]

The regions in teal are where the difference in means $\Delta$ is positive, and the regions in dark blue are where it is negative.

Zooming in on the upper dark blue region:

[image: contour1]

The red line in the second figure is where $\lambda_0 = \lambda_1$.

We find that the two regions are connected, with a boundary at $\lambda_0 = \lambda_1 \equiv B \simeq 1.338$.
In addition, there is a vertical asymptote at $V \simeq 0.5049$.

So it seems that contrary to our intuition, this effect is real.
**The mean of the non-central Poisson deviance distribution can be lower than that of its associated central distribution**, even in the simple case of $N=1$ measurements. In other words, the wrong model matches the data better than the correct model.

Is there an intuitive explanation for why this occurs, and for the $\lambda_0$ and $\lambda_1$ that it does?
Or perhaps does the Poisson deviance formalism break down in these regimes?
Any insight here would be appreciated.